# Php-fpm status page is not displayed

Tags: php-fpm

I've try to get php-fpm status page.
When i open /status page in a web browser or directly to fcgi - it says File not found.

Could you help - how to fix this.

```
# grep -ER "status|ping" /etc/php5/* | grep -v ":;"
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:pm.status_path = /status
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:ping.path = /ping
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:ping.response = pong 

# SCRIPT_NAME=/status SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status QUERY_STRING=  REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php-fpm-www.sock
Primary script unknown
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html

File not found.

# SCRIPT_NAME=/ping SCRIPT_FILENAME=/ping REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php-fpm-www.sock
Primary script unknown
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html

File not found.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just had the same problem and I am just going to describe what i needed to make it work. You have not shared many details on your php-fpm config or your nginx (if this is what you are using as a web server). Notice you might need to run the instructions below with sudo/as root in front of the commands to have the rights to modify the files or restart services.

In php-fpm config

```
vi /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Search for the status path directive and enable it

```
pm.status_path = /status
```

Then make sure nginx can call this location. In you nginx site config

```
vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.conf
```

Add

```
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
     access_log off;
     #allow 127.0.0.1;
     #allow 1.2.3.4#your-ip;
     #deny all;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 }
```

Notice above i have commented out the allow and deny instructions to have the status page enabled from any IP. Make sure this is not enabled on production.
Now restart both nginx and php-fpm

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Calling the status page from the browser should now work

Answer (score 5):

For php7.0 use these codes to enable the status.

**In default file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/**

```
location /status {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    log_not_found off;
    }
```

**Uncomment the following line in www.conf (file) in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d (location)**

```
pm.status_path = /status
```

**Restart both nginx/php7.0**

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

Now in the web browser, type this address to get a full detailed report of currently running php scripts in the currently active web server where php7.0 is configured to work.

```
http://yoursite.net/status?html&full
```

Additionally, make sure to keep it password protected in order to protect it from intruders as explained in here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 2):

Just chipping in since the other answers didn't solve it for me.

All I needed to do (after setting up fpm pool config and the nginx `location`) was
`touch status`
in the nginx site root.

I don't know how much of the following is necessary, but it works:

```
location ^~ /status {
    access_log off;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

`^~` can be replaced with `=`. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority for more info

Comment: +1 for touch status, did it for me as well

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Curious was curious about this as well. php-fpm only cares that the `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameters correspond to the value of `pm.status_path` setting.

Thus the following is the minimal nginx location to access the status information:

```
location = /a_random_path_here_ODY1NjY3Mj/fpm-status {
    include fastcgi_params;

    #'/status' is the value of pm.status_path in /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME '/status';
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME '/status';

    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

By explicitly stating the parameter values the status page location can be called anything and can be on any path, not just `/status`. Having a random path also helps prevent generating unnecessary log entries from all kinds of scanners.

In a production setting one would obviously add `allow`/`deny` directives or password protection for the location, but the above is the minimal necessary configuration.

One would do a similar thing for the ping uri (`ping.path` setting) if enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2.
Found, that these lines were recently added to default `snippet/fastcgi-php.conf`

```
# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
```

And since there is no file for `pm.status_path` - it returns 404;

So, for me - I had to remove `include snippet/fastcgi-php.conf`

You still need to pass `REQUEST_METHOD`, `QUERY_STRING`,`SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. Just do it without `snippet/fastcgi-php.conf`. Often you will have  `fastcgi.conf`, which will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk and the problem was something else. After looking at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335820/836064), I tried explicitly adding a `SCRIPT_FILENAME` directive and it worked.

In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}
```

You seem to need this because the included `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` does not set any value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, and PHP needs it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do this from the command line on debian.

*as root*

```
watch service php5-fpm status
```

Comment: The question was not about whether the process is running or not.