# php-fastcgi status: "No input file specified"

Tags: nginx, monitoring, php-fpm, stat, php-fastcgi

```
# grep pm.status_path /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
pm.status_path = /fcgi-status
```

nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/(fcgi-status|ping)$ {
     access_log off;
     allow 127.0.0.1;
     deny all;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
}
```

fastcgi_param and fastcgi_pass are the same as for the website which works.

php-fastcgi and nginx were restarted, but:

```
# curl http://127.0.0.1/fcgi-status -i
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2016 08:10:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20

No input file specified.
```

This is not duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/716996/php-fpm-status-page-is-not-displayed) because the error is not 'File not found' (perhaps nginx was unable to find the path) but 'No input file specified'. Please note there *is* php header in the response, so the answer came not from nginx but from php-fpm.

This is the only pool on the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found: I messed fpm and fast-cgi. The config changes were made in fpm, but I run fast-cgi.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` has a path prefix in it, however in `php-fpm` configuration you don't have a prefix.

So you need to change either one so that they are the same.

Comment: 'path' here is file path, like /home/site/docroot. Tried `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;` and `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /$fastcgi_script_name;`, no luck. Or I should use something different?

Comment: Did you try just `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /fcgi-status`?

Comment: have just tried, doesn't work.