# php-fpm status page returns 404

Tags: php-fpm

(I have read and applied the recomendations [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/716996/php-fpm-status-page-is-not-displayed) - it did not resolve my issue).

I am trying to read the PHP-FPM status page on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This is using the packaged PHP/PHP-FPM (7.4.3) and nginx (1.18.0)

In /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf, I have uncommented the line:

```
pm.status_path = /status
```

(and restarted php7.4-fpm). In my default server conf I have added:

```
        
        location /status {
                allow 10.0.0.0/8;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
                # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
```

(and reloaded nginx. The commented out entry was a slightly different fcgi config I use elsewhere - it doesn't work either). I have also tried adding a `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` withing the location block - no change in behaviour. I am connecting from an allowed address - and commenting out the allow/deny lines has no impact on the behaviour:

- accessing http://$MYSERVER/status returns a 404
- Adding a directory named status in the document root results in a 403 (directory listing not allowed).
- If I place a PHP script in $DOCROOT/status/ it is executed when I enter its URL in my browser - so the request is being passed off to PHP-FPM.

There is nothing reported in /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log nor /var/log/nginx/error.log . The access.log only reports the 403/404 status.

It appears that php-fpm is simply not intercepting the request but is handing it off to PHP.

I have also tried with a different string for pm.status_path. Same result.

How can I get further insights / fix this issue?

Comment: I've copied your config into a basic server setup and it seems to work. Have you tried killing all processes and restarting it ruling out any stuck configurations?